# min difference between two unsorted arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have to find min absolute difference between two elements of unsorted arrays.
My approach is to first sort both the array, run a loop over one array and find lower bound of each element of this array in another array.

And then check whether it is minimum or not and store it for further comparisons

Test Case:

```
2
8 1 3 5 7 9 7 3 1

8 2 4 6 8 10 8 6 2

8 2 3 5 10 9 3 2 1

7 1 2 6 12 13 3 2
```

Output :

```
1
0
```

result : passed

Explanation:

1) min will be abs(a[7]-b[7])

2) min will be abs(a[0]-b[(1)])

But when i am submitting to spoj I am getting  wrong answer ,it look like I am missing some thing else .

problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC11B/

Please help where I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector <int> a;
vector <int> b;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int na;
        cin>>na;
        for(int i=0;i<na;i++){
            int temp;
            cin>>temp;
            a.push_back(temp);
        }
        int nb;
        cin>>nb;
        for(int i=0;i<nb;i++){
            int temp;
            cin>>temp;
            b.push_back(temp);
        }
        sort(a.begin(),a.end());
        sort(b.begin(),b.end());
        int ans=a[0]-b[0];
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            int bval = lower_bound(b.begin(),b.end(),a[i])-b.begin();
            ans = min(ans,abs(a[i]-b[bval]));
            if(bval>0)
            ans = min(ans,abs(a[i]-b[bval-1]));
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
        a.clear();
        b.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to post online judge contest code, you should first get rid of all of those input statements and instead, *hard-code* the data into the program.  No one is going to sit there and type in the data over and over again when they attempt to run your code.

Comment: Your code cannot produce the output you describe.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, of course, but I give OP credit for admitting he's cheating. /s

Comment: @OP [This is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48d6c5bd5342cb23).  No need to input data over and over again, and the code can be tested easily.

Comment: `int ans=a[0]-b[0];` should be `int ans=std::abs(a[0]-b[0]);`

Comment: Is there a need to sort the arrays, why not try max(abs(max(A)-min(B)), abs(Max(B)-min(A))). The max and min of the arrays can be found in O(n)

Comment: @Jarod42 its still not passing Please brother help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version has several issues:

- `a[0]-b[0]` which might be negative, invalidating remaining computation.
- lower_bound which might result in `b.end()` leading to out of bound access.

You can do something like the following:

```
std::size_t min_distance(std::vector<int> v1, std::vector<int> v2)
{
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    auto it1 = v1.begin();
    auto it2 = v2.begin();
    auto min = std::abs(*it1 - *it2);

    while (min != 0 && it1 != v1.end() && it2 != v2.end()) {
        min = std::min(min, std::abs(*it1 - *it2));
        if (*it1 < *it2) {
            ++it1;   
        } else /*if (*it2 <= *it1)*/ {
            ++it2;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ZmdgAL)

Comment: Your above  comment made my solution accepted but thanks for writing the solution
Love from india